Есть ли в этих предложениях ошибки (стилистические)
Здравствуйте, уважаемые участники! Делаю задание уже битый час, никак не могу понять, где здесь ошибки. Буду признателен за разъяснения 1. Наиболее интересные номера, лучшие активные участники фестиваля будут премированы и включены в ансамбль песни и пляски. 2. Пора это понять всем руководителям, и отчёты представлять вовремя, и подходить к ним со всей серьёзностью. 4. Ветер хоть и обдавал лицо и тело прохладой, но обжигал щёки и шею. 5. Иванов был высокий, худощавый человек средних лет, с усами и бритым выдающимся подбородком и выпуклыми мутными глазами. 8. Комитет установил руководство и контроль за работой нашей организации.

Короче, как что называется не скажу, но примерно так: 1) все плохо: номера и участники будут премированы и включены - сделали однородными то, что однородными не является и склеили все в один ком. Но мера будут премированы, а участники будут включены - нужно противопоставить, тогда норм.2) слишком много местоимений, не понятно что "это" и "к чему подходить со всей серьёзностью" - к начальникам? подходить к этому... - но тоже не хорошо.4) лицо - это щёки тоже, тело - это шея тоже, поэтому противоречие обдувал прохладой, но обжигал.

Спасибо большое!


возможно, описание характеристик тела перемешано в описанием физиономии. Иванов был высокий... . Лицо его с усами и бритым подбородком, а глаза выпуклые и мутные... . - разделить на два предложения и поделить - конституцию, внешнюю мо(р)ду, и собственно описание глаз. - по принципу: тело-форма, лицо(внешность), душа.8) Плеоназм(это знаю, как называется хD) - комитет установил руководство или комитет установил контроль.


@Буратино Иванов был высокий, худощавый человек средних лет, с усами, бритым выдающимся подбородком и выпуклыми мутными глазами. // Здесь только союз  И нужно было убрать, а так все на месте. Сначала обозначены отличительные черты, а дальше перечисляются характерные в свободном порядке. Это же художественное описание, а не протокол в полиции по стандартной форме. Но  это не стилистика, а пунктуация.

Я бы написала так:

Комитет установил руководство и контроль за работой в нашей организации.

Дело в том, что сочетание руководство и контроль (за чем?)  используется как устойчивое сочетание, что видно из практических примеров в Нацкорпусе:
Методическое руководство и контроль за осуществлением мониторинга безопасности гидротехнических сооружений возлагается на Госгортехнадзор России и его региональные органы.
Лучше предложное управление: в нашей организации. Это больше похоже на правовые возможности комитета.

Присоединяюсь к вашему ответу. Можно написать и так: установил руководство за нашей работай и контроль  за ней. Но ваш вариант,кажется, лучше.

Спасибо, Серж!  Я пыталась составить разные комбинации из "руководства и контроля", но ничего не получалось.  А потом вспомнила, что слова часто используется в виде сочетания.

Вообще некоторые предложения показались мне не совсем правильными.

Таких примеров много в заданиях ЕГЭ. Ответ прост: в качестве однородных членов не следует употреблять два или более слов, управляющих разными падежами существительных или других частей речи. Поэтому предложение № 8 должно выглядеть так: "Комитет установил руководство работой нашей организации и контроль за ней".

Установить руководство работой ,— разве грамотно?

В общем, мой вариант про "комитеты" такой):
Комитет назначил руководство и установил контроль за работой нашей организации.

Второй ответ
         Я леплю из пластилина,
         Пластилин нежней, чем глина,
         Я леплю из пластилина
         Кукол, клоунов, собак.
         Если кукла выйдет плохо,
         Назову ее "Дуреха",
         Если клоун выйдет плохо,
         Назову его "Дурак"...
              
         сл.Н.Матвеевой. муз.С.Никитина


Предложения в этом задании тоже придумали  и "слепили"  КРИВО, то есть они однозначно кривые  сами по себе, а к ним дополнительно "добавлены" стилистические ошибки, которые должны найти школьники. Что ж, им можно посочувствовать, но, с другой стороны, пусть привыкают к жизни)

Вот о каком комитете здесь речь? Это информация из Сети:
Какие основные комитеты как правило создаются при Совете 
директоров?
В соответствии с Уставом при Совете директоров Общества 
могут быть созданы в том числе следующие комитеты:
Комитет по аудиту;
Комитет по надежности;
Комитет по кадрам и вознаграждениям;
Комитет по стратегии и развитию;
Экспертный комитет;
Комитет по безопасности.


Итак, комитет —  это подчиненная структура,  как она будет назначать руководство?  По большому счету  это право учредителя/собственника компании, а Совет  директоров действует по его указанию.  Комитет чаще связывается с общественной работой.
 КОМИТЕТ, -а; м. [франц. comite от лат. 
 committere 
 - поручать]. 1. Выборный коллегиальный орган, 
 руководящий какой-л. работой. Исполнительный к. 
 Местный к. профессионального союза. 2. Орган 
 государственного управления, выполняющий 
 определённые функции. К. по экологии. 
 Комитетский, -ая, -ое. К-ие комиссии.


Посмотрим толковый словарь для глагола «установить», там два подходящих значения: учредить и наладить/организовать.


Тогда можно предложить такой вариант: Совет директоров сменил руководство, а также  установил контроль за работой в нашей организации.
Имеется в виду, что какое-то руководство в компании было и до его смены.

Вообще говоря, присоединительный союз а также позволяет более свободно комбинировать однородные члены: Комитет установил (учредил) руководство, а также контроль за работой в нашей организации.

Словарь
УСТАНОВИТЬ,  св. что. 1. Поставить, поместить где-л., в каком-л. месте или надлежащим образом 3. Осуществить, наладить, организовать. У. наблюдение за чем-л. У. взаимовыгодные отношения. У. связь с редакцией газеты. У. контакт со зрителями. У. тишину в классе. // Достигать высоких показателей, результатов. У. мировой рекорд. У. рекорд производительности труда. 4. Добиться создания, осуществления чего-л.; учредить. У. новую власть. У. таможенную службу. У. заводу производственный план. У. новые органы власти. // Утвердить, узаконить, ввести в действие. У. цену. У. расписание. У. нормы выработки.

Комитет разный бывает, бывает комитет партии, бывает комитет министров(Высший совещательный и распорядительный орган при российском императоре в 1802–1906 годах.). Комитет партии сменил руководство завода и установил контроль за производством. Хотя конечно, тут есть проблема с тем, что не указано, какой именно комитет и к чему он относится - собственно к "организации" или это вышестоящий комитет?

@Буратино КОМИТЕТ – от поручать. Комитет министров в 1802–1906 годах исполнял поручения императора, ЦК КПСС – поручения народа-собственника. А сейчас комитет исполняет поручения Генерального директора или Совета директоров, назначенного собственником- учредителем, даже если это государство. Статус комитета снижен и руководство он назначать/устанавливать не может.

Мы же не знаем, какой это комитет, и какого года, обрывки какие-то информации.

А если не знаем, то как определить правильность стилистики и редактировать предложение?  Школьники все-таки ориентированы на современную действительность, а не на  прошлый век.

Нет никакой современности, есть язык, есть владение языком, можно все поломать, но будет хрень, а не современность. Про Вавилонскую башню слышали историю? Вот это современность. Мем будет, современный, но мем.

Не возражаю. Но в чем причина того, что на эту хрень невозможно дать очевидно правильный ответ, а предлагаются разные варианты, которые идеальными не назовешь. Например, руководство, которое  должен установить/учредить/определить непонятно какой  комитет.  Это слово сейчас имеет другое частотное значение, которое более понятно школьникам.

"сейчас комитет исполняет поручения Генерального директора" - ген директору принадлежит несколько организаций. Ген дир назначил комитет, комитет выбрал руководство и установил контроль.

Сомневаюсь, однако, похоже на утопию.  Может, в Китае где-нибудь так, но не у нас. Комитеты решают частные вопросы в организации, а общее руководство у Ген. директора. Там даже вроде бы не комитеты, а замы по разным направлениям.  А при них могут быть комитеты. Другими словами, комитет – это нечто другого уровня, не руководящего.  Именно это важно для заданного предложения.
